# openvpn can't sudo within "down" script when shutting down systemd service

Tags: openvpn, systemd, sudo

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

My VPN config has directives:

```
user ovpn
group ovpn
up "/path/to/my/script"
down "/path/to/my/script"
```

My visudo file has the directive:

```
%ovpn ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables
```

This allows openvpn to deescalate from `root` to the unprivileged user `ovpn` (for security reasons), but still use `iptables` to bring up and down routes loaded from a database. It works if I invoke the openvpn process directly from a shell, i.e.:

```
$ sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/vpn0.conf
```

and then kill it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. By "it works" I mean that the iptables rules are added and removed as desired without any errors.

However, if I start and stop the openvpn process using the vanilla Ubuntu systemd openvpn service. i.e.

```
$ sudo systemctl start openvpn
$ sudo systemctl stop openvpn
```

then the "--down" script fails during execution of the "stop" command. When I examine the syslog I see that the --down script has failed at the shell command invoking `sudo /sbin/iptables`, specifically where it is attempting to fork the process. (regarding error message, my script is a python script using `subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/sudo', '/sbin/iptables', ...])`. Error message is:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
  return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1235, in _execute_child
  self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

If I remove the `user` and `group` directives from the openvpn configuration file so that the process remains `root` throughout execution, then I don't get the error, and the iptables invocations work as expected, even when using the systemd service to start and stop.

So it smells like systemd is preventing me from escalating privileges using `sudo` while shutting down the service.

Any ideas on how to overcome this difficulty while still deescalating to an unprivileged user?

Comment: sudo may need a tty. try `Defaults:%ovpn !requiretty`

Comment: I added the `!requiretty` line as requested, with no change in observed behaviour. I also tried a vanilla `Defaults !requiretty` line, also with no change in observed behaviour.

Comment: I dont use openvpn, but on my Fedora system the systemd openvpn Unit file `openvpn-client@.service` has an entry `LimitNPROC=10`. This would limit the number of processes that can run simultaneously in the service (when User= not root). Perhaps you can try increasing this a tad?

Comment: I changed it to `LimitNPROC=1000` in the equivalent openvpn server Ubuntu 16.04 config file and everything started working! I wonder what the reasoning is behind that limit. I'm gonna try bringing it down to 100 to see if that will work with my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, in this case `Resource temporarily unavailable` was telling me that `os.fork` was failing because the unprivileged user had hit the maximum number of processes allowed by the openvpn service's systemd config.

To fix this, I edited `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service` and made the following change:

```
- LimitNPROC=10
+ LimitNPROC=100
```

And subsequently my `iptables` chain tear down commands are succeeding even when using an unprivileged user and elevating privileges using sudo.

Comment: I would recommend you create `override.conf` instead of editing files in `/lib/systemd/system`. I mean create `/etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service.d/override.conf` with contents:
`[Service]`\n
`LimitNPROC=100`
By the way, in my case 100 was not enough. I used 1000.